# How to web scrape thomasnet website to get suppliers information in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract supplier information like supplier name, location, annual revenue, year founded, number of employees, product description etc from https://www.thomasnet.com/ for a particular location and category. For example, I want to extract all 201 suppliers information for category "Battery" and location "Southern California".

I am copying the url of each page for category "Battery" and location "Southern California" and getting the supplier information. But is there any way to automate the process such that I will get all the suppliers information if I put the category and location (irrespective of the number of pages for that search)?

This is what I am doing right now.

```
import requests
import ssl

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url = 'https://www.thomasnet.com/southern-california/batteries-3510203-1.html'
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

supp_lst = soup.find_all( class_ = "profile-card__title" )
for data in supp_lst:
    # Get text from each tag
    print(data.text)
    
supp_location_lst = soup.find_all( class_ = "profile-card__location")
for data in supp_location_lst:
    # Get text from each tag
    print(data.text)

supp_content_lst = soup.find_all( class_ = "profile-card__body profile-card__mobile-view read-more-wrap")
for data in supp_content_lst:
    # Get text from each tag
    print(data.text)

supp_lst = soup.find_all(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data")
for data in supp_lst:
    # Get text from each tag
    print(data.text)
```

I am very much new in web scraping. Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciated. TIA.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the pagination in URL and last page marker (Sorry we've found no mathes...) to iterate over all pages.

This example script collects supplier names:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_supplier_names() -> list[str]:
    all_supplier_names = []
    i = 1
    while True:
        r = requests.get(
            f'https://www.thomasnet.com/southern-california/batteries-3510203-{i}.html',
            headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            },
        )
        if not r.ok or 'Sorry, we found no matches' in r.text:
            break  # no data -> last page was reached in previous iteration

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        supplier_names_raw = soup.find_all(class_='custom-control-input selectco')
        found_supplier_names_on_page = [x['data-coname'] for x in supplier_names_raw]
        print(f'Found {len(found_supplier_names_on_page)} suppliers on page {i}')
        all_supplier_names.extend(found_supplier_names_on_page)
        i += 1

    return all_supplier_names


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_supplier_names())
```

Comment: Did you run my script as-is, or you've modified it? If you launch it as is it in the answer -  it woks with no errors.

Comment: I want to extract suppliers' annual revenue, year founded, number of employees as well. But I am not able to do it using supp_lst = soup.find_all(class_ = "profile-card__supplier-data")
for data in supp_lst:
    print(data.text). This is giving me annual revenue, year founded, number of employees all concatenated.

Comment: your script worked perfectly after I removed "list[str]".

Comment: Ah, looks like you use an older version of Python (pre 3.9 I suppose) which does not recognize new-style type hints. Okay I'm glad my answer helped)